# Swig template, testing condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swig-template

how can i do something like this with swig-template?

```
var remId = $(this).attr('remId');
if (remId) {
    var end = remId.search('_');
    var underscore = remId.slice(end, end + 1); 
    var Id = remId.slice(end + 1, remId.length);
}
```

for example, if remId = 123455_instock_white
i need to find out if remId has instock or prestock.

so if Id contains instock, Id will go under instock table
and if Id contains prestock, Id will go under prestock table.

any idea? how shold i filter this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use most of what is available in base JavaScript. If you know that `remId` will be a string, use `indexOf` to test if `instock` or `prestock` is in the string.

```
{% if remId.indexOf('instock') !== -1 %}
    remId has instock
{% elif remId.indexOf('prestock') !== -1 %}
    remId has prestock
{% endif %}
```